# Can't get systemd to run a script

Tags: systemd, mutt

Here's my `mailsync.service` and `mailsync.timer` files located in `~/.config/systemd/user/`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mail sync

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Nice=10
ExecStart=/home/singularis/.local/bin/systemd/mailsync
Environment="HOME=/home/singularis"
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync emails with mbsync on schedule

[Timer]
OnBootSec=2m
OnUnitActiveSec=2m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Here's the content of `/home/singularis/.local/bin/systemd/mailsync`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

MBSYNCRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mbsync/mbsyncrc"
alias mbsync="mbsync -c $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mbsync/mbsyncrc"

# Run only if not already running in other instance
pgrep mbsync >/dev/null && { echo "mbsync is already running."; exit ;}

export GPG_TTY="$(tty)"

[ -n "$MBSYNCRC" ] && alias mbsync="mbsync -c $MBSYNCRC" || MBSYNCRC="$HOME/.mbsyncrc"
[ -n "$MPOPRC" ] || MPOPRC="$HOME/.config/mpop/config"

lastrun="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/neomutt/.mailsynclastrun"

# Settings are different for MacOS (Darwin) systems.
case "$(uname)" in
  Darwin)
    notify() { osascript -e "display notification \"$2 in $1\" with title \"You've got Mail\" subtitle \"Account: $account\"" && sleep 2 ;}
    ;;
  *)
    case "$(readlink -f /sbin/init)" in
      *systemd*|*openrc*) export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$(id -u)/bus ;;
    esac
    # remember if a display server is running since `ps` doesn't always contain a display
    pgrepoutput="$(pgrep -ax X\(\|org\|wayland\))"
    displays="$(echo "$pgrepoutput" | grep -wo "[0-9]*:[0-9]\+" | sort -u)"
    notify() { [ -n "$pgrepoutput" ] && for x in ${displays:-0:}; do
      export DISPLAY=$x
      notify-send --app-name="mutt-wizard" "New mail!" " $2 new mail(s) in \`$1\` account."
    done ;}
    ;;
esac

# Check account for new mail. Notify if there is new content.
syncandnotify() {
  acc="$(echo "$account" | sed "s/.*\///")"
  if [ "$1" = "pop" ]; then
    # Handle POP
    mpop "$acc"
  else
    # Handle IMAP
    if [ -z "$opts" ]; then mbsync "$acc"; else mbsync "$opts" "$acc"; fi
  fi
  new=$(find\
    "$HOME/.local/share/mail/$acc/"[Ii][Nn][Bb][Oo][Xx]/new/ \
    "$HOME/.local/share/mail/$acc/"[Ii][Nn][Bb][Oo][Xx]/cur/ \
    -type f -newer "$lastrun" 2> /dev/null)
      newcount=$(echo "$new" | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l)
      [ -z "$MAILSYNC_MUTE" ] && case 1 in
      $((newcount > 0)) ) notify "$acc" "$newcount" ;;
  esac
}

# Sync accounts passed as argument or all.
if [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; then
  for arg in "$@"; do
    [ "${arg%${arg#?}}" = '-' ] && opts="${opts:+${opts} }${arg}" && shift 1
  done
  accounts=$*
fi

[ -z "$accounts" ] && accounts="$(awk '/^Channel/ {print $2}' "$MBSYNCRC" 2>/dev/null)"
[ -z "$pop_accounts" ] && [ -x $MPOPRC ] && pop_accounts="$(awk '/^account/ {print $2}' "$MPOPRC" 2>/dev/null)"

# Parallelize multiple accounts
for account in $accounts; do
  syncandnotify "imap" &
done

for account in $pop_accounts; do
  syncandnotify "pop" &
done

wait

notmuch new --quiet

#Create a touch file that indicates the time of the last run of mailsync
touch "$lastrun"
```

Here's the output of `journalctl --user -xeu mailsync.service`:

```
Nov 28 10:44:16 singularis systemd[871]: Failed to start Mail sync.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1336 and the job result is failed.
```

Am I missing something? I got this code from [Luke Smith](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/mutt-wizard/blob/master/bin/mailsync).

Comment: Does your script `/home/singularis/.local/bin/systemd/mailsync` have **execution** permissions?

Comment: Yes. It does. I ran `chmod +x /home/singularis/.local/bin/systemd/mailsync`.

Comment: Maybe the problem is what you have in the script. I see you have defined an `alias`. But given that you are not using an interactive shell then the alias will not work. Try adding (after `#!/bin/sh`) this: `shopt -s expand_aliases`

Comment: Or you can change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/sh -i`

Comment: Btw, I suggest you use `functions` instead of `aliases`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I've figured out the solution. Here's the newly modified script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

num=$(ps aux | pgrep "mbsync" -c)
if [ "$num" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "mbsync is already running."; exit ;
fi

export HOME=/home/singularis
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export XDG_DATA_HOME="$HOME/.local/share"
export GNUPGHOME="$XDG_DATA_HOME/gnupg"
export PASSWORD_STORE_DIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/password-store"
export MBSYNCRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mbsync/mbsyncrc"
export NOTMUCH_CONFIG="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/notmuch/config"
export LASTRUN="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mailsynclastrun"

mbsync() {
  command mbsync --config="$MBSYNCRC" "$@"
}

notmuch() {
  command notmuch --config="$NOTMUCH_CONFIG" "$@"
}

notify() {
  notify-send \
    --icon="/usr/share/icons/oomox-xresources-reverse-flat/status/scalable/mail-unread-symbolic.svg" \
    --app-name="neomutt" \
    "$1" "$2"
}
new_notify() {
  notify "New Mail" " $2 new mail(s) in \`$1\` account."
}

syncandnotify() {
  acc=$(basename "$1")
  opts="$2"

  if [ "$opts" = "" ]; then
    mbsync "$acc"
  else
    mbsync "$opts" "$acc"
  fi

  new=$(find \
    "$HOME/.local/share/mail/$acc/"[Ii][Nn][Bb][Oo][Xx]/new/ \
    "$HOME/.local/share/mail/$acc/"[Ii][Nn][Bb][Oo][Xx]/cur/ \
    -type f -newer "$LASTRUN" 2> /dev/null)

  newcount=$(echo "$new" | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l)
  [ "$newcount" -gt 0 ] && new_notify "$acc" "$newcount"
}

if [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; then
  for arg in "$@"; do
    first_char="${arg%"${arg#?}"}"
    [ "$first_char" = '-' ] && opts="${opts:+${opts} }${arg}" && shift 1
  done
  accounts=$*
fi

if [ "$accounts" = "" ]; then
  accounts=$(find "$HOME"/.local/share/mail -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -iname ".*" \))
fi

for account in $accounts; do
  notify "Syncing $(basename "$account")"
  syncandnotify "$account"
done

wait

notmuch new --quiet

touch "$LASTRUN"
```

and here are my two `mailsync.service` and `mailsync.timer` files:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mail sync

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/singularis/.local/bin/systemd/mailsync
Environment="HOME=/home/singularis"
RestartSec=900

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Mail sync

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15m
OnUnitActiveSec=15m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```